# It doesn't write more than 3 tables

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I created this class for my Android app:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME = "db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String table1="CREATE TABLE users(";
        table1+="_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table1+="city TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table1+="name TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table1+="info TEXT);";

        String table2 = "CREATE TABLE things(";
        table2+="id TEXT PRIMARY KEY);";

        String table3 = "CREATE TABLE rec(";
        table3+="id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table3+="text TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table3+="rate INTEGER NOT NULL);";

        String table4 = "CREATE TABLE avg(";
        table4+="mct TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table4+="rec INTEGER NOT NULL,";
        table4+="avgrate FLOAT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(table1);
        db.execSQL(table2);
        db.execSQL(table3);
        db.execSQL(table4);
    }
}
```

It doesn't write table4 to local SQLite database. If I add comment to any previous db.execSQL(tableX), it works.
For example if I comment db.execSQL(table2) it write table1, table3 and table4.
If I remove comment it writes table1, table2, table3... and no table4... why?
It seems that it can't write more than 3 tables. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you determine which tables are "written" and which are not?

Comment: I use SQLite Editor app for Android.

Comment: Change column `text` to another name into table 3.

Comment: Likely the app doesn't work. Check for your tables in your code.

Comment: Done... nothing changed, As i said in my question i can write table4 if i comment any other previous db.execSQL(tableX);

Answer (score 4):

`avg` is a reserved word in SQLite, so you'd better rename your last table.

Comment: Done... nothing changed and it cannot change because as i said i can write table4 if i comment any other previous table write...

Comment: FWIW, it's not a syntax error to use a function name as a table name. Functions are identified by their `()` parens.